# Html agility pack not loading url

Tags: c#, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I have something like this:

```
class MyTask
{
    public MyTask(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
        IsBusy = false;
        Document = new HtmlDocument();
    }

    public HtmlDocument Document { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsBusy { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var task = new MyTask(1);
        task.Document.LoadHtml("http://urltomysite");
        if (task.Document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='some-class']").Count == 0)
        {
            task.IsBusy = false;
            return;
        }   
    }
}
```

Now when I start my program, it throws an error on the `if` sttement, saying that `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`. Why isn't it loading my page? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are looking for `.Load()`.

`.LoadHtml()` expects to be given physical HTML. You are giving a website to go to:

```
HtmlWeb website = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument rootDocument = website.Load("http://www.example.com");
```

Comment: Don't worry i will do it, you need to wait 15 minutes in order to accept answer.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Arran's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19793443/2145211)

If `.SelectNodes("//span[@class='some-class']")` doesn't return any nodes and is `null` then doing a `Count` on it will give this exception.

Try

```
if (task.Document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='some-class']") != null && 
    task.Document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='some-class']").Count == 0)
    {
        task.IsBusy = false;
        return;
    }
```