# Using HTMLAgility to get value from pre tag

Tags: html, vb.net, parsing

I'm having trouble getting a single value from an HTML pre tag. Here is the html

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css"></style>
</head>
<body>
<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">123456789</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried using a few examples, but can't ever seem to get the value I need. I've been using vb examples.

Tried the following, but getting a null exception error

```
    Dim doc As New HtmlDocument()
    Dim website As New HtmlWeb()

    website.Load("http://webURL.com")

    doc.LoadHtml(website.ToString)

    For Each pre As HtmlNode In doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//pre")
        MsgBox(pre.InnerText)
    Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should have shown us at least something of what you have tried and what the value you need is.**

I am guessing that you want "123456789" from the page at the (unspecified) URL:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports HtmlAgilityPack

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim srcUri = "http://127.0.0.1/index.html"

        Dim wc As New WebClient
        'TODO: put in error handling for the download
        Dim pageText = wc.DownloadString(srcUri)

        Dim doc As New HtmlDocument()
        doc.LoadHtml(pageText)

        For Each pre As HtmlNode In doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//pre")
            MsgBox(pre.InnerText)
        Next

    End Sub
End Class
```

**Edit**: Code above edited to load from a URL instead of using a string.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. That is the info I was after. Would you be able to tell me how to alter to use html from a url?

Comment: @user3572565 Please see [Html agility pack not loading url](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19793443/1115360).

Comment: Thanks again. I see there is a difference between the two (Load & LoadHTML), but not sure if I've gotten my head around it. Can you help again please? I've updated question with code.

Comment: @user3572565 I've modified the code to download a web page instead of using a string. Using a `WebClient` seemed to be the easiest way. Running the code in the Form.Load event proved to be unreliable, so I put it into a Button.Click event handler instead.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks for that. I've been trying and trying to get this working and kept failing. Thanks again!